# Css and font loading

Tags: css, fonts

Where does the web page search for font's specified in the CSS.  Does it look in more than one place?  Can it look in the same directory as the external css or nested css/html file on a server, or only on the clients computer?  What is the steps or order of events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a `@font-face` declaration for a given font, and the browser understands it, it'll parse it and download the font from the URL(s) specified. Otherwise (or if the first location to look in is `local()`), the browser checks the computer's database of installed fonts, and if it's installed it uses the font for rendering.

If the font still can't be found, and there are other fonts in the font stack (a list of fonts as defined in [`font-family`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-family-prop)), this will be repeated for each font in the stack until a font is found that can be used. The last fallback font will be the browser's default and/or an inherited font.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fonts on the client's computer or font's on the server accessed with [CSS font embedding](http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680).